# Is there a term to generalize the renowned, classic sentences

Tags: phrases, terminology

For example, sentences like "There is a first time for everything".

Comment: Idioms, axioms, aphorisms, maxims...it may well depend on what you consider to be a _classic sentence_.

Comment: Thanks. "aphorism" and "proverb" are what I am looking for.

Comment: *Cliche* may also apply.